# NoSuchMethodError showing for Jira when Java running as Web application, But gets output when running in main

Tags: java, tomcat, jira, nosuchmethoderror, jira-rest-java-api

I am creating a Java web application. I added Jira API jars for connecting to Jira to get Issues created in Jira.

And this is my Java program to get the issues

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.NullProgressMonitor;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.domain.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyJiraRestClientFactory;

public class AppJIRADataCollector {

    final static JerseyJiraRestClientFactory factory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        AppJIRADataCollector appJira=new AppJIRADataCollector();
        appJira.getIssues("http://localhost:8080/", "AP-1", "admin", "admin");
    }

    public void getIssues(String issueURI,String issueKey,String username, String password) {

        try {
            final URI jiraServerUri = new URI(issueURI);
            final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri,username, password);
            System.out.println(restClient);
            final NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();
            final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient()
                    .getIssue(issueKey, pm);

            System.out.println(issue);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("URI not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this program, I am getting the output correctly as it prints the issues.

But when I run this as web application, and calling the `getIssues()` method from servlet, tomcat showing `NoSuchMethodError`

Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Iterables.contains(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.json.IssueJsonParser.parse(IssueJsonParser.java:216)
    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.json.IssueJsonParser.parse(IssueJsonParser.java:59)
    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient$1.call(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:85)
    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:54)
    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.getAndParse(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:80)
    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient.getIssue(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:131)
    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient.getIssue(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:123)
    com.domain.jirademo.adapters.AppJIRADataCollector.getIssues(AppJIRADataCollector.java:22)
    com.domain.jirademo.controllers.ProjectDefectsServlet.doPost(ProjectDefectsServlet.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Why this is happening? Any problem with JARs? I am using maven. If want I will post the `pom` also.

***EDIT***

I added the main method later only. So in the stack trace, line 22 refers to

```
final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient()
                        .getIssue(issueKey, pm);
```

Comment: The JAR containing `com.google.common.collect.Iterables.contains` likely isn't on the classpath. This class is likely in a file named `guava-*.jar`. In a web application, JAR files usually go under `WEB-INF/lib`. Further, make sure that no JAR file named `google-collections-*.jar` is on the classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoSuchMethodError it's caused by a version mismatch, you should check your version of guava library.